# Traversing an array of objects and comparing them

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, switch-statement, traversal

I have an array of objects which are in a React **state**.  `state = { badgeCounts: [], };`
This array updates constantly. (each time a new genre is added/ state is set)

This is the code I get when I console.log(badgeCounts)

```
{data: Array(3), status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config: {url: "api/badge/badgeidcount", method: "get", headers: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), …}
data: Array(3)
0: {_id: 28, count: 2}
1: {_id: 53, count: 2}
2: {_id: 18, count: 1}
length: 3
```

...

My goal is to render a badge(png image) only when an **'_id'** reaches a **count** of 10.

```
{this.state.badgeCounts.map((genId) => {
            switch (genId._id) {
              case 28:
                return <Badge variant="primary">Action</Badge>;
              case 18:
                return <Badge variant="primary">Comedy</Badge>;
```

I believe I would then need to update or set the **state**??? (I am learning React)

I'm having trouble with the code and logic and best way of approaching checking for every **_id** and their **count**. I'm not sure how to proceed.  I have it in a switch statement (which I can change if it's not a practical approach) right now but can't check the **count** (I have a total of 19 possible **_id**'s that could appear in the array with their respective **counts**)

Thanks.

Comment: If it is a static list:

`const matchingItem = this.state.badgeCounts.find(item =>item.id === 10);
if (matchingItem){
 return <badge>;
}`

Comment: Are you already able to inject new badges data to your state with any logic? If yes, then you're very close to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use Material-UI, but I made a JS Fiddle with basic React. I don't know how you're injecting more badges in the state, but you didn't say if and how you did. For the rest, it would be better to just avoid the switch and create a mapping object between Badge ID and Badge Information. Next, to display only when count >= 10, you would filter the array before calling map. Here is a an approach:

```
class BadgeApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    
    this.state = {
        badgeCounts: [
        {_id: 28, count: 2},
        {_id: 53, count: 10},
        {_id: 18, count: 7},
        {_id: 60, count: 6},
        {_id: 70, count: 15},
      ]
    };
    
    this.mapping = {
      28: 'Action',
      53: 'Romance',
      18: 'Comedy',
      60: 'Sci-Fi',
      70: 'Horror',
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Badges:</h2>
        <ol>
        {this.state.badgeCounts.filter(genId => genId.count >= 10)
          .map(genId => (
          <li key={genId._id}>
            <span>{this.mapping[genId._id]}</span>
          </li>
        ))}
        </ol>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<BadgeApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

The JS Fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/6pk3t87s/1/

If ever you need more information for the Badges, then you can try a more complex mapping object like:

```
this.mapping = {
  28: { name: 'Action', color: '#0f0' },
  53: { name: 'Romance' , color: '#ff0' },
  18: { name: 'Comedy', color: '#00f' },
  60: { name: 'Sci-Fi', color: '#000' },
  70: { name: 'Horror', color: '#f00' },
}
```